# getUserMedia browser api doesn't capture mute events on Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, getusermedia, navigator, mute

I am writing a piece of code to listen to audio mute events using the userMedia api in browsers. Steps I followed -

1. Added this piece of code to the browser console

```
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true}).then(function(stream) {
  let tracks = stream.getAudioTracks();
  console.log("Tracks", tracks);
  let defaultTrack = tracks[0];
  defaultTrack.onmute = function(event) {
    console.log("Muted", event);
  }
}).catch(err => console.log);
```

2. Granted permissions to the respective audio device in the browser tab (Chrome and Firefox)
3. At the system level, I muted this device that I selected in the browser.

**On chrome console:**

```
Muted Event {isTrusted: true, type: "mute", target: MediaStreamTrack, currentTarget: MediaStreamTrack, eventPhase: 2, …}
```

I see the muted event on chrome but not on Firefox. Am I missing something?

Note: I am doing this on a Mac. I think that shouldn't matter.

Comment: _"Note: The condition that most people think of as "muted" (that is, **a user-toggled state of silencing a track**) is actually managed using the `MediaStreamTrack.enabled` property, for which **there are no events**."_ (MDN: [MediaStreamTrack: mute event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStreamTrack/mute_event))

Comment: Yes I understand it but why is there a difference in behaviour in chrome and firefox? @Andreas

Comment: From the mentioned note I would assume that Firefox works as expected, so that would be a question for the Chrome guys why they trigger the event (I couldn't reproduce the effect on Windows with the latest Chrome+FF).